# Prove the existence of a multiplicitive Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field, such that $$F=\{a+b \sqrt{2}\}$$ Such that a and b are rational numbers.

Prove there exists a multiplicative identity.

I just expanded the product of two elements, and collected like terms.  I know the coefficient of the $\sqrt{2}$ must be zero since a, b are rational numbers.

But from there, I am stuck.

Comment: If you're looking for an identity, why not just consider $1$?

Comment: Crap, I meant to say inverse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ (over the reals) is given by

$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}$$

The question is: Can this be written in the form $p+q\sqrt{2}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$?

The answer is: Yes!

To see how, we can "rationalise the denominator":

$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}} \times\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a-b\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}=\left(\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}\right)+\left(\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\right)\sqrt{2}$$

Clearly, we need $a^2-2b^2 \neq 0$ for this to be valid. But since $a^2-2b^2=0 \iff a=\pm b\sqrt{2}$, and $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ we see that $a^2 - 2b^2 \neq 0$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: To find the inverse of $a + b \sqrt{2}$, use$$(a - b \sqrt{2}) (a + b \sqrt{2}) = a^2 - 2b^2$$

And $a^2$ is never equal to $2b^2$, so.......